# General Network Infrastructure

Tags: networking, firewall, infrastructure, traffic-shaping

I have a number of servers that I rent out to people and have started growing to a point where I need better management. Specifically I am interested in being able to police bandwidth and block port 25 outgoing totally. All I have right now in my infrastructure is a Catalyst 3500XL. I don't want to break the bank and would love any suggestions on some decent cheap hardware solutions for allowing me to:

1. Block Port 25
2. Set a Specific Bandwidth Right 1MB but allow people to use more if available
3. Set an overall bandwidth CAP
4. Have SNMP so I can monitor via Cactai what is going on in the network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a firewall with traffic shaping capabilities to do what you're asking -- the Catalyst 3500 switches, while quite capable, aren't up to this kind of task.

You can consider building your own firewall using a server and something like [pfSense](http://www.pfsense.org) (which is more than adequate for small environments and very budget-friendly), or investing in commercial solutions from [Cisco](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps5708/Products_Sub_Category_Home.html) or [Juniper Networks](http://www.juniper.net/us/en/products-services/security/netscreen/).

Comment: To expand upon my answer a bit - you also probably want to consider breaking your environment into vlans if you haven't already (this will let you monitor traffic per-customer relatively easily & apply other network-level restrictions)

Comment: Any hardware firewall that I can buy say under $500 that you think will do the job?

Comment: You can certainly buy or build a server with at least 2 NICs for under $500, and pfSense is free...